# Character Comparison QWERTY Key Proximity Typo (Access VBA Equivalent)

Tags: vba, ms-access, multidimensional-array, vb6, user-defined-types

This requires a solution & the code to migrate to Access from VB6 is below. 
I have a function to compare characters that comes from VB6 and I am a novice user on VB6 and mostly work from VBA platform. I need to setup a class or a better way in MS Access to check character by character for typo mistakes without the use of UDT.

Mytypolist as an array refers to the following dataset:
QWA      WESAQ    ERDSW    RTFDE    TYGFR    YUHGT    UIJHY    IOKJU    OPLKI    PLO      AQWSZ    SEDXZA  DRFCXSE  FTGVCDR  GYHBVFT  HUJNBGY  JIKMNHU  KOLMJI   LPKO     ZASX     XZSDC    CXDFV    VCFGB    BVGHN    NBHJM    MNJK

The above data is used to compare if a character was mistyped in a word.. ex. if I use A as in Auebec instead of what I mean to type Quebec, my cluster of interest is QWA; WESAQ; AQWSZ; or any other Q arrangement on a standard English Qwerty keyboard based on proximity. And this is not just for Q, but for entire set of alphabets, regardless of case, so c has its own cluster of possible typo matches etc..

In VB6 setup of UDT (user defined type):
'declare UDT type for typos

```
Public Type Mytypos
    Rightrkey As String * 1
    PossibleKey As String * 8
End Type
'declare arrays and variable for master list and typos
Public Masterlist() As String
Public Mytypolist(26) As Mytypos
Public Matchkey As Mytypos
```

the following function  compares two words; and assign similarity by calculating currentpct score:

```
Public Function CompareCharacters(ByRef MasterWord As String, _
ByRef Checkword As String, ByRef CurrentPCT As Double, _
ByRef WordVal As Long) As Double

'define function variables
Dim ChrCount As Long
Dim ChrValue As Long
Dim loop1 As Long
Dim loop2 As Long

'define the letter values
If Len(MasterWord) > Len(Checkword) Then
    ChrCount = Len(MasterWord) * 2
Else
    ChrCount = Len(Checkword) * 2
End If

ChrValue = 1 / ChrCount

'say CURRENT PCT has a value of 10%

'check each letter for a match in current word position
For loop1 = 1 To Len(Checkword)

            'check for typo errors (key proximity)
            For loop2 = 0 To UBound(Mytypolist)
                Matchkey = Mytypolist(loop2)
                'if indexkey = letter in masterword
                If Matchkey.Rightrkey = Mid(MasterWord, loop1, 1) Then
                    'does the letter in the checkword exist in the proximity keylist
                    If InStr(1, Matchkey.PossibleKey, Mid(Checkword, loop1, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        'value for letter found in proximity keylist
                        CurrentPCT = CurrentPCT + ChrValue
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next loop2

Next loop1
CompareCharacters = CurrentPCT

End Function
```

IF you can post me a array/class solution that may not produce compiler issues (String UDT in VBA are a problem). Please check it out now!

Answer (score 0):

It would probably best, since you have a 1 character to 8 character thing, to just have a full mapping.  Something to replace this:

```
Public Type Mytypos
    Rightrkey As String * 1
    PossibleKey As String * 8
End Type
```

To:

```
PossibleKeys(255) As String * 8
```

That way, each character (from 0 to 255) would have the 8 character mapping.  No UDT required!